# How do I create a constraint on the number of relationships between two nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to create a constraint like this:

`create constraint on (a:NodeTypeA)-[r:TYPE_OF_REL]->(b:NodeTypeB) ASSERT count(r) < 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/constraints/#query-constraint-prop-exist-rels), Neo does not support this.

Answer (score 2):

You can kind of get the same result by using `MERGE` instead of `CREATE` whenever you create such a relationship. For example:

```
MATCH (a:NodeTypeA {id: 123}), (b:NodeTypeB {id: 456})
MERGE (a)-[r:TYPE_OF_REL]->(b);
```

The `MERGE` will not create the relationship if it already exists.

(Note, however, that duplicate relationships are still possible if multiple `MERGE` operations can run concurrently. This is not a concern if you are using a neo4j 3.1.2 or later, or the DB is only asked to perform one operation at a time.)

Comment: I think the [bug](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/8629) you're referring to was fixed in [Neo4j 3.1.2](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-3.1-changelog#312). Since the fix, concurrent MERGE operations shouldn't produce duplicate relationships.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Cool! Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my answer.